# Java ECLIPSE Nearest TSP with Nearest Neighbour Algorithm

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, traveling-salesman

First question I ask here on the forum, had some use on many questions posted here. I am stuck with my current assignment: I need to make a TSP with a nearest neighbour algorithm and then store the shortest "route" in an array.

So far, I came up with this:

```
public class Q2b {

    int route[] = new int[179];//create route array
    private int nFacilities; // 179.
    private int nLocations; // 179.
    private DistanceMatrix dm; // ass_1distances.
    private boolean[] isIncluded;//create boolean for customer cluster open/closed.

    public Q2b(int nClusters, String dmFile) {

        this.isIncluded = new boolean [179];//set the length of the array isIncluded equal to n locations.
        for (int i= 0; i < nLocations; i++)
            isIncluded[i]=false;//set the value of customer cluster included to false
        this.nFacilities = nClusters;
        this.nLocations = nClusters;
        dm = new DistanceMatrix(nFacilities, nLocations);
        dm.loadFromFile(dmFile);
        Q2bsolution();
    }


    public void setIncluded (int location, boolean isIncluded)  {
        this.isIncluded[location]=isIncluded; //set the location to is included.
    }

    public double Q2bsolution() {
        double totalDistance = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.nLocations; i++) {
            while (isIncluded[i]==false)    {

                double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;

                for (int j = 0; j < this.nFacilities; j++) {

                    if (i != j) {
                        if (this.dm.getDistance(i, j) < min) {
                            min = this.dm.getDistance(i, j);
                            this.isIncluded[i]=true;
                            route[i]=j;


                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(route[i]);
                //System.out.println("Distance to closest connection to customer cluster " + i + " = " + min);
            }

        }
        return totalDistance;
    }
}
```

To walk you through my code without having to figure it out yourself:

`nLocation` and `nFacilities` refer to my distance matrix, there are 179 location to be served, and facilities can be put on the same 179 locations. First I set all locations to `isIncluded = false`, to state that no location is added in the array route. Then I say that for my 179 locations I take the minimum distance starting from row 0. My code is giving me the following output now:

2 2 0 8 20 4 ... et cetera, which means the closest location to location 0 is location 2, the closest location to location 1 is location 2, the closest location to location 2 is location 0 .... et cetera. However, I need to figure out how to start at location 0, get location 2 as shortest distance, and THEN go on from location 2 to get the shortest distance from that one, et cetera.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to continue with the shortest location once I calculated that, can you guys help me out?

Kind regards,

Stephen